# ClassicThesis to B5paper

Tags: margins, paper-size, classicthesis

I'm using ClassicThesis v.4.1. for my Thesis. The thesis should be published in B5 size.

How do I adapt `classicthesis` (A4) to B5? 
I have tried

```
\usepackage[a4paper,layout=b5paper,twoside,layouthoffset=17mm,layoutvoffset=23.5mm, showcrop]{geometry}
```

It gives me A4 paper with cropmargins for B5 paper. When cropped, margins are marginal and the footer and header are cropped out.

What I really would like it to be is to have B5paper with reasonable font size and reasonable margins.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: This seems to be a related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86920/how-to-adapt-classicthesis-layout-to-b5paper-and-linux-libertine?rq=1

Comment: I agree that the question is the same. Nevertheless, the answer didn't help me as it results in situation that I've described above. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Geometry needs two arguments for b5-paper:

- the first option has to be b5paper to specify the actual paper format
- the second option (layout) has to be b5paper as well, as it is used to calculate the lengths for the margins.

So if you write

```
\usepackage[b5paper,layout=b5paper]{geometry}
```

it should work.